# Is there a way to ensure that text elements are truly aligned to the vertical middle?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout, flex4, flex-spark

I've often had this problem in the past and to this date haven't found a good solution that works universally.

Essentially, the problem is this. If I want to align things vertically in a container, I'll use `verticalAlign="middle"`, but this doesn't exactly solve the problem of truly aligning text vertically. Text is always too high vertically, so in the past, I've just adjusted `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` to compensate, but that doesn't work as the font for `_sans` differs from operating system to operating system.

Given the following layout code, you'll see the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Group width="100" height="50">
        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%" radiusX="5" radiusY="5">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="#333333"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" 
                paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"
                paddingRight="10" paddingLeft="10"
                verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:Line width="100%">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#CCCCCC" weight="1"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:Label text="100 Percent!" top="10" bottom="10" 
                left="10" right="10" verticalAlign="middle"
                textAlign="center" color="#FFFFFF"/>
    </s:Group> 

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"
                verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:Application>
```

What happens is pretty clear. The horizontal line gets aligned to the exact middle of the box, but the text is offset by some arbitrary amount. I assume that this is because of the text baseline alignment or something. Is there a way to fix this regardless of the font size and face? I'd like to have the line essentially go right through the middle of the text, ignoring the extra space possibly needed for below the logical line of text (ie: ignore the bottom part of "g's" and "j's" when laying things out).

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a Textflow with strike through text instead of having a stroke across?

Comment: Did you try using the properties verticalCenter and horizontalCenter.Atleast in Flex 4 they seem to be available

Comment: @J_A_X The whole point is to demonstrate that the center is off for text elements. If I did strikethrough text, that would defeat the point.

Comment: @Neeraj What should one set those values to?

Comment: both to 0 , flex automatically places the center of the child object over the center of the window.The verticalCenter propertly, tells flex that the center of child object is at distance of "x" vertically from the center of the window object/application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently not, though a custom solution might exist.

Answer (score 0):

Look into layout constraints. You could also look into a simple binding expression for them to calculate the exact needs on the fly. Although they are generally perfect as is.

They also respond to the resize event bubble nicely.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm not sure what a layout constraint is. Is this a solution which will work regardless of font size and face?

Comment: No problem:

The code looks like this <s:Label text="100 Percent!" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>


its an offset from center.

If you are using flex builder, in your properties pallete for a component in design mode, scroll to the bottom and you will a representation of your component in a boundary with tick boxes this lets you set its positional behaviour.

You can also look at alignmentBaseline for text specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<s:Group width="100" height="50">
   <s:Line width="100%" verticalCenter="0">
      <s:stroke>
         <s:SolidColorStroke color="#CCCCCC" weight="1"/>
      </s:stroke>
   </s:Line>

   <s:Label text="100 Percent!" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:Group>
```